# Does AWS SWF let work flow to sleep some time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Every time a customer completes a transaction a reminder workflow starts for that customer which tries to remind a customer about few actions that he/she has to perform. There are points in the flow where I know for sure that there is no task to be performed. So in this case I want the workflow to go to sleep for some time and come back to life later. I want this sleep feature to avoid database call as my decider does one database query every time it gets a task.

I have gone through the AWS documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-welcome.html) . But found nothing there (Please point me to document if the feature exists). Does AWS-SWF provide such a feature. If it does not provide a feature of this type then what is smart and clean way of doing this.

A small example of flow I want to create :

```
1. End of transaction initiates a "simple workflow"
2. Decider gets a task. Decider decides to give it to a Customer 
Reminder activity worker or PUT IT TO SLEEP.
3. The decider keeps poling but never gets the workflow till the sleep 
time of work flow is over.
4. The sleep time is over so SWF starts giving it the decider which has
been polling all along.
```

Please tell me if you need any more clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [StartTimerDecision](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_StartTimerDecisionAttributes.html) to create a timer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the timer documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-timers.html